# How to attach screenshot to extent report in cucumber java

Tags: java, testng, cucumber-java, selenium-extent-report

I am using Cucumber java and Extent report. I am able to generate report, capture the screenshot for the failed test case. However, for some reason, it is not attaching the screenshot to the extent report.

I am using the below dependencies in pom file

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>7.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In Hooks.java, I have written below code

```
@AfterStep
    public void AddScreenshot(Scenario scenario) throws IOException
    {
        WebDriver driver =testContextSetup.testBase.WebDriverManager();
        if(scenario.isFailed())
        {
        File sourcePath=    ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(sourcePath);
        scenario.attach(fileContent, "image/png", "image");
        }
    }
```

In the src/test/resources folder,

1. I have created extent-config.xml which a standard template
2. I have created extent.properties file as below:

```
extent.reporter.html.start=true
extent.reporter.html.config=src/test/resources/extent-config.xml
extent.reporter.html.out=test-output/extentreports/extent.html
screenshot.dir=test-output/ExtentReport/screenshots
screenshot.rel.path=./screenshots/
```

As you can see from the image, [image]
it has successfully created the screenshot,however it does not attached it in the report.

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I managed to solve this issue! Screenshot path was incorrect. Corrrected it.

Comment: Checkout boilerplate code: https://github.com/nitinsmartsense/smartsense-cucumber-testng

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue! Screenshot path was incorrect. Corrrected it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the **extent.properties** file screenshot.rel.path is not correct

> screenshot.rel.path=./screenshots/

Please use this.

```
extent.reporter.html.start=true
extent.reporter.html.config=src/test/resources/extent-config.xml
extent.reporter.html.out=test-output/extentreports/extent.html
screenshot.dir=test-output/ExtentReport/screenshots
screenshot.rel.path=../screenshots/
```